# Adding text to layout?

Tags: android, string, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I have a layout for a small screen in landscape. I have some text in a TextView in the layout...but **it is not showing up**. I have not defined any text size font, nor have I set any dimentions. Yet, the textview's text is not showing up:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_container"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="20:00"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Yet, the TextView is empty...Here is an image showing the design layout screen:

[image]

Here you can see the text is clearly set:

[image]

Why is the text not showing up? This is extremely odd, and I have tried quite a few things, but the problem persists. I have tried:

- Restarting Android Studio
- Refreshing the design view
- Build -> Clean project
- Build -> Rebuild project

Yet, the problem persists. I appreciate your assistance in completing this problem.

### Weird thing is, this is only for layout Small-landscape. It works fine in regular layout and Small layout. It is the same code...

Comment: set a background color for layout or change the textcolor

Comment: @Dhina I tried changing textcolor, but it still doesn't show up.

Comment: I doubt your marginbottom is hiding the textview?

Comment: I guess that was the problem...Then, why was the textview still showing on the screen, like in the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you missing `textColor` .Just add this

```
android:textColor="#00FF00"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Reason

```
 android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
```

**layout_marginBottom** is the main *culprit* in here .The size `25dp` absent in your small device .That's why have problem .

Comment: This textView is in a LinearLayout which is above a relativeLayout with the ID of relativeLayout

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Which theme are you using ?

Comment: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: @RuchirBaronia  okay .Remove `android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"` for testing case .Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543392/textview-is-not-visible

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Glad to helped . Move Ahead .

Answer (score 0):

Try Layout Height and width to match_parent or some value, as textview would of zero height as it is dependent on Layout / or change the height, width of Textview to wrap_content